# Why Reads in Log file are more than writes in SQLServer Database?

Tags: performance, sql-server-2019

In my office environment, there are databases for which reads in log files are more than writes.

[image: File IO Stats - 3X Reads in Log File]

The above screenshot represents **3x reads** in log file compared to write in one of the database. This dashboard data is calculated using 2 snapshots of data captured using below query as part of [open source tool SQLMonitor](https://github.com/imajaydwivedi/SQLMonitor?tab=readme-ov-file#why-sqlmonitor). [Sample FileIOStats dashboard](https://ajaydwivedi.ddns.net:3000/d/database_file_io_stats/t___database-file-io-stats?orgId=1&var-sqlmonitor_datasource=ygPVA4snk&var-server=21L-LTPABL-1187&var-inventory_db=DBA&var-is_local=1&var-dba_db=DBA&var-ip=fe80::cab1:7f0e:21bd:3ed6%2514&var-fqdn=WORKGROUP&var-collection_time_utc=1707828600796&var-sql_schedulers=8&var-sqlserver_start_time_utc=1707459128693&var-disk_drive=__All__&var-database=DBA) exposing similar metrics in my own lab environment.

```
select  [collection_time_utc] = sysutcdatetime(), 
        d.name as [database_name], d.database_id, mf.name as file_logical_name, mf.file_id, mf.physical_name as file_location,
        vfs.sample_ms, vfs.num_of_reads, vfs.num_of_bytes_read, vfs.io_stall_read_ms, vfs.io_stall_queued_read_ms,
        vfs.num_of_writes, vfs.num_of_bytes_written, vfs.io_stall_write_ms, vfs.io_stall_queued_write_ms, 
        vfs.io_stall, vfs.size_on_disk_bytes, 
        ps.io_count, ps.io_pending_ms_ticks_total, ps.io_pending_ms_ticks_avg, ps.io_pending_ms_ticks_max, ps.io_pending_ms_ticks_min
from sys.dm_io_virtual_file_stats(null,null) vfs
join sys.master_files mf on mf.database_id = vfs.database_id and mf.file_id = vfs.file_id
join sys.databases d on d.database_id = mf.database_id
left join ( select  r.io_handle, 
                    io_pending_ms_ticks_min = MIN(io_pending_ms_ticks),
                    io_pending_ms_ticks_max = MAX(io_pending_ms_ticks),
                    io_pending_ms_ticks_avg = AVG(io_pending_ms_ticks),
                    io_pending_ms_ticks_total = SUM(io_pending_ms_ticks),
                    io_count = COUNT_BIG(*)
            from sys.dm_io_pending_io_requests as r 
            where r.io_type = 'disk'
            group by r.io_handle
        ) ps
    on ps.io_handle = vfs.file_handle;
```

A couple of obvious reasons I can think of causing high reads in log files are -

- We have 3-4 tables that are published as part of transaction replication
- Transaction rollbacks reading the log back to restore to pre-transaction state

**My question is what could be real reason for this high read on log files compared to writes?**

Got to this point while troubleshooting high disk io latencies on SQLServer.